# How can I add a conditional to override this undefined value when there is no dummy account in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, null, undefined, typeerror

Im getting an "TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined" when there is no account in the data, which holds the type attribute. Is there any ways I can bypass or hold off on this till till there is a dummy account provided? I have been searching for answers. I tried the try catch block as well. I have provided a image of the accounts prop being passed into the file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmZwA.png)

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    const { currentAccountId, accounts } = props;
    const currentAccountType = currentAccountId ? accounts.filter(acc => acc.id === currentAccountId)[0].type : null;

    const { currentTab } = state;
    if (currentAccountType === ACCOUNT_TYPES.MANUAL && (currentTab === ACTIVITY_TABS.OPEN_ORDERS || currentTab === ACTIVITY_TABS.ORDER_HISTORY)) {
      return {
        ...state,
        currentTab: ACTIVITY_TABS.BALANCES,
        transactionsDialogOpen: false,
      };
    }
    return state;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use optional chaining:

```
const currentAccountType = currentAccountId ? accounts.filter(acc => acc.id === currentAccountId)[0]?.type : null;
```

But thats something only supported in newer versions of node so maybe just do it on 2 lines instead?

```
const currentAccount = accounts.find((acc) => acc.id === currentAccountId);
const currentAccountType = currentAccount ? currentAccount.type : null;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. However, its giving my a syntax error.

Failed to compile
Syntax error: Unexpected token (117:105)

Comment: Ah its probably because its something new and not supported in the version of node you are using. Just do it on 2 lines instead: const currentAccount = accounts.find((acc) => acc.id === currentAccountId);
const currentAccountType = currentAccount ? currentAccount.type : null;

Comment: Nice! That worked wonders! Now im just getting this same issue with this function:

 <AccountTypeIcon type={this.getAccountById(account.id).type} />

Not sure how to go about this part. Its the same error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Comment: Try this: <AccountTypeIcon type={(this.getAccountById(account.id) || {}).type} />

Comment: That seems to have done it! Thanks! I think just one last one, and it is all good. Im getting the same error here, just with "assets" property being undefined. Not sure how to implement that method you taught me  when the syntax is like this:
filterViewBalances() {
  74 |   const { holdingsByAccount, holdingsByAsset, currentAccountId } = this.props;
  75 |   if (currentAccountId) {
> 76 |     return holdingsByAccount.find(acct => acct.id === currentAccountId).assets;
  77 |   }
  78 |   return holdingsByAsset;

Comment: Same thing like before: return (holdingsByAccount.find(acct => acct.id === currentAccountId)|| {}).assets

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it!